# El subjuntivo o el indicativo con los verbos de afección, sentimiento o emoción

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Entiendo que los verbos de afección, sentimiento o emoción usualmente inducen el modo subjuntivo, pero pueden admitir a veces el indicativo (según ese [enlace](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/Subjuntivo%20o%20indicativo%20con%20verbos%20de%20afecci%C3%B3n.htm#:%7E:text=Los%20verbos%20de%20afecci%C3%B3n%2C%20sentimiento,pero%20admiten%20ocasionalmente%20el%20indicativo.&text=Estos%20verbos%20rigen%20indicativo%20cuando,se%20sobrepone%20al%20contenido%20emotivo.) de Hispanoteca). Pero todavía a veces tengo dudas - si tengo que usar el indicativo o el subjuntivo en algunas situaciones.

"*Qué bien que **disfrutaste**/**hayas disfrutado** de tu evento*" - ¿Puede usarse el indicativo en vez del subjuntivo si solamente quiero enfatizar el aspecto informativo ["Vale, disfrutaste de eso y es algo bueno para ti"]?

"*Me gusta cuando **hay**/**haya** mucha gente en ese boliche*" - ¿Puede usarse el indicativo aquí si solamente revelo mis gustos como un hecho?

"*Tú eres tan importante para mí que realmente te **echaba**/**echara** de menos*" - Como lo entiendo, ¿tanto el indicativo como el subjuntivo son posibles (por lo menos, me lo dijo un nativo hispanohablante)? ¿De qué depende eso aquí?

"*Quería demostrarte lo importante que **fueras**/**eras** para mí*" - Como lo entiendo, ¿tanto el indicativo como el subjuntivo son posibles? ¿De qué depende eso aquí?

"*Me alegra saber que a ti te **importa**/**importe** eso*" - Como lo entiendo, ¿tanto el indicativo como el subjuntivo son posibles? Aunque un nativo hispanohablante durante nuestra comunicación me escibió que "**importa** es correcto", creo que ambas variantes son posibles.

Y 2 ejemplos adicionales:

"*¡Qué bien eso...que **te sientes** mejor!*" - ¿Puede usarse el indicativo aquí? Creo que con el subjuntivo puede ser algo como un deseo, aunque debería usarse coma en este caso, supongo ("*Qué bien, ¡que **te sientas** mejor!*" [porque te lo deseo realmente], y con el subjuntivo **sin coma** puede ser algo como emotivo [el significado sería: me siento feliz porque te sientes mejor ahora].

"*¡Qué bueno saberlo eso...que te **gusta** esa cosa!*" - la misma pregunta que en el ejemplo anterior. ¿Puede usarse el indicativo aquí y de qué depende eso?

UPDATE: Justo hoy tuve que responder a una foto recibida y lo hice así porque de verdad eso era más emotivo que informativo para mí: "*¡Qué lindo eso...lo que **hagas**!*". Pero incluso aquí tengo algunas dudas. Entonces, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Qué bien que disfrutaste de tu fiesta. No hay razón de utilisar el subjuntivo. Si pones el subjuntivo, quiere decir que hay duda. No hay duda. Es lo que dice alguien.

Comment: A no ser que quieras hacerlo a fin de expresar cuanto te alegra que la haya disfrutado. El subjuntivo no solo expresa duda.

Comment: Las frases con "Qué no-se-que" son una opinión, de un locutor. No hay rázon de ponerlas en el subjuntivo. Por ejemplo: ¡Qué lindo eso...lo que haces!". La persona lo está haciendo. No hay duda.

Comment: Reitero: el subjuntivo **no** solo expresa duda, y el que se **use** no significa que alguien **dude** de algo. :)

Comment: Alex, ninguna frase tuya (leyendo rapido) no lleva el subjuntivo. Creo que no has entendido los verbos correctamente....

Comment: @Lambie No, ahora lo entiendo. Por eso me confundí "el que se exprese una emoción no significa de plano que el subjuntivo se deba usar", porque pensaba lo contrario.

Comment: Alex, exactamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con ninguno de los ejemplos que proporcionaste se puede usar el subjuntivo, solo con aquellas exclamativas hay una alternancia entre los dos modos.

***Qué bien que te divertiste*** (me dijiste que te habías divertido)

***Qué bien que te hayas divertido*** (me alegro de que te hayas divertido)

---

**Me gusta cuando** ***HAY*** **mucha gente** (*cuando* no induce el subjuntivo en este ejemplo; pero sí en: "Me *gustará* cuando *haya* mucha gente" porque *cuando* se refiere a un momento en el futuro)

**Tú eres tan importante para mí que realmente te** ***ECHABA*** **de menos** (no hay nada que induzca el subjuntivo aquí)

**Quería demostrarte lo importante que** ***ERAS*** **para mí** (es un hecho; no hay nada que induzca el subjuntivo)

**Me alegra saber que a ti te** ***IMPORTA*** **eso** (*saber* en afirmativo siempre induce el indicativo)

Al final, el que se exprese una emoción no significa de plano que el subjuntivo se deba usar. Tampoco se usa únicamente para expresar una emoción u opinión: hay muchas reglas sintáticas y ocasiones en las que el subjuntivo no tiene nada que ver con la afección/emoción/opinión, como cuando denota la irrealidad/negación/acciones futuras.

---

PD: "*Qué bien, ¡qué te sientas mejor!*" es una frase exhortativa. Le estás diciendo que se sienta mejor o que esperas que se sienta mejor.

Comment: @nopaeltepec Ahora entiendo. Creo que por eso "el que se exprese una emoción no significa de plano que el subjuntivo se deba usar" me confundí antes, porque antes pensaba a veces lo contrario y por eso tenía dudas en algunos momentos parecidos.

Comment: @Alex Es mucho más mecánico de lo que se suele creer; es decir, la misma idea se puede expresar en varias formas, pero la manera en la que se estructure la frase dictará el uso del subjuntivo.